# Microsoft Speech Recognition Properties Tweaking

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

Microsoft Speech Recognition can be tweak using properties (
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine_properties.aspx)

- initialSilence
- babble
- endSilence
- endSilenceAmbiguous

I'm looking for use case tweaking these properties. For instance what should I do
- If I want to match a short word like yes / no
- If I want to match a long sentence

How these properties will fit with SubSetMatching mode (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.subsetmatchingmode(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

BTW: is there a way to set SubSetMatching mode in the XML of the Grammar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reducing the `BabbleTimeout` can be useful in noisy environments.  In quieter environments, however, this may result in prematurely finalizing a recognition.

Reducing `InitialSilenceTimeout`, `EndSilenceTimeout`, and `EndSilenceAmbiguousTimeout` can be useful if the commands are short, and you're looking for a faster response from the engine.  Again, however, reducing the timeouts too far can result in recognitions being prematurely finalized (i.e., the recognizer finishes before you've finished speaking).

These properties are handled in the audio processing portion of the SR engine, and don't affect SubsetMatchingMode.

And, as far as I know, there's no way to control the SubsetMatchingMode via XML.

Comment: Thanks, I saw the GrammarBuilder use SubsetMatchingMode is there a description of what it did ? At last it build a Grammar but I don"t understand how it skip short words for instance ? Does't it build a complexe grammar ? Or is there magic tricks ?

Comment: SubsetMatchingMode is *conceptually* equivalent to building a complex grammar, but it's not implemented that way.

Comment: Last little question (may be I should put it elsewhere) is there a way to build a grammar that only do <ruleref special="GARBAGE"> without previous words to get any audio with a duration of a sentence (matching properties)

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeEncausse I'd ask that as a separate question, as the answer is bigger than a comment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21303742/microsoft-speech-recognition-wildcard-blank-content