# Microsoft Speech Recognition: wildcard blank content

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

In my Speech Engine I activate / desactivate multiple grammars.

In a special step I'd like to run a Grammar with ONLY  to capture Audio of next given sentence according to engine's properties.

But to start/stop matching something, I assume engine needs "words". So I don't know how to do it ?

(Underlaying explanation: my application convert all garbage audio to text using google speech API because dictation is too bad and no available on Kinect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, actually, no, the SR engine only needs to know that the incoming audio is "speech-like" (usually determined by the spectral characteristics of the audio).  In particular, you could use the [`AudioPosition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognizer.audioposition%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property and the [`SpeechDetected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognizer.speechdetected%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`RecognitionRejected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognizer.speechrecognitionrejected%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) events to send all rejected audio to the google speech API.

So your workflow would look like this:

1. Ask question of user.
2. Enable appropriate grammars.
3. Wait for recognition or recognition rejected.
4. If recognition, process accordingly
5. If recognition rejected, collect retained audio & send to google speech API.

Comment: Ok so if I understood, here is my workflow: 1. I ask a question to user. 2. I enable a given Gramamr 3. I need a "wildcard answer" 4. I process the answer. So I do not do 2./3. and I play with "speech detected" because only will not trigger the grammar

Comment: Updated answer to be more explicit.  (it's hard to do lists in comments.)